# jQuery .next().not() can't find dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an input element after a clicked element, only if it doesn't exists. The `.next().not()` function works but it seems it cannot find dynamically created elements.

```
$(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    if($(this).next().not('input')){
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var currentText = ($(this).text());
    var input = $('<input type="text" >');
    var saveBtn = $('<button type="button">Save</button>');
    input.val(currentText);
    saveBtn.click(function(){
     currentElement.text(input.val());
    $((input).remove());
    $((this).remove()); 
    });
    input.insertAfter(this);
    saveBtn.insertAfter(input);

      }
  });
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phutis/ycxkT/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.not()` is not a boolean function, it's a selector -- it returns the elements of the given set that don't match the selector. To tell if a selector finds anything, test its length.

You don't need to use `.not()` at all. `.next('selector')` returns the next element if it matches the selector, otherwise it returns an empty collection.

```
if ($(this).next('input').length == 0) {
    ...
}
```